# Application requesting and Getting info from second application

Tags: c#, wpf, database, windows

Hi I'm busy with a project in C# that can provide the user with info.
The idea is that there is 2 application. 
1. The user UI that has no connection to the DB.(WPF)
2. Has no User interface but has a connection to the DB and to a local cache.(C#)

So Application 1 communicates to application 2 only.
application 2 communicates with local cache and DB on the command of application 1

Any idea on how to set up the communication between both application?

Comment: Why wouldn't you embed this in one application?

Comment: To extend Derp's comment. Why? Client/server architecture is a good thing **when needed**. Do you actually need it **in this moment**? To split a good designed application (where layers and separations already exist) is - almost - trivial to do in future. To answer your question: IPC (check MSDN for this). For two (or more) .NET applications easiest approach may be WCF (again, check MSDN)

Comment: The reason for the split is that we need some way to get the info to the user as soon as the process is complete server side (some action are instant other can take up to 48 hours) so if it is 1 application the user have to open the application every now and again to check if the info is back or not.

Comment: Will they communicate with each other via the internet? Look into web services (Web API 2) for your service layer or Application 2 as you named it. Your App 1 could initially call a end point that kicks off a service, and periodically calls a different end point to check on the status of running tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Application 1 is called client, and App2 can be called a service. There are many implementations, e.g.

```
1. App2 is a publisher
2. App1 is a subscriber
```

You can use some queues (e.g. [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/)) as the bridge/broker. App2 writes some messages to a queue, and  app1 subscribes to the message queue, whenever a message is published by App2, app1 will be notified and custom message handling can be fired.

[image]

[image]

Some tutorials to get started quickly:

- [Using RabbitMQ in C# (I) Installation of RabbitMQ](https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2015/08/13/using-rabbitmq-in-c-i-installation-of-rabbitmq/)
- [Using RabbitMQ in C# (II) Sending message to RabbitMQ](https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2015/08/13/using-rabbitmq-in-c-ii-sending-message-to-rabbitmq/)
- [Using RabbitMQ in C# (III) Consuming messages from RabbitMQ](https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2015/08/17/using-rabbitmq-in-c-iii-consuming-messages-from-rabbitmq/)